# r gbm and dismo for present available data

Tags: r, gbm

I want to use the r gbm (and dismo) package for present and available data 
with the functions gbm.step, predict.gbm, gbm.interactions, gbm.plot and gbm.perspec.
My presences are coded as 1 and random available points are coded as 0.
The number of presence observations is the same as the number of random available points.
Will the results be useful as the packages are designed for present/absent data and if so, how must predicted values and the plotted fitted values be read?

Comment: take a look on another questions - always include code and describe what you did and what was not working.

Comment: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and also read: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html . Those are good bits of advice but you should also consider the possibility that this is not the right venue for your level of understanding. If you are not ready to start programming with a particular set of data, then perhaps the statistics oriented CrossValidated.Com or the http://datascience.stackexchange.com/  (beta) venue would be a better fit.